# How to append dynamic path in JSTL c:url value

Tags: jquery, html, spring-mvc, jsp

I want to append a dynamic path in JSTL C:URL value. Below i declared a anchor tag

```
<a href="" id="intentCsv" class="btn add-intent" role="button">
```

This is my jquery code.

I am trying to append href value dynamically in above anchor tag:-

```
var url = "urlPath";

$('#intentCsv').attr("href", "<c:url value='csv/downloadIntentCSV/"+${url}+"' />");
```

But it's giving me an error that:-

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"
```

On clicking anchor tag I want to invoke below method and print the url inside the method.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/csv")
public class CSVUploadController {

@RequestMapping(value="/downloadIntentCSV/{url}")
public Object downloadIntentCSV(@PathVariable String url)  
{
    System.out.println("Inside Mehtod"+url);
    //some code
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVC

```
<a href="<c:url value="/csv/downloadIntentCSV/${YOURDYNAMICVALUE}"/>" >hello</a>
```

In the controller follow these

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadIntentCSV/{YOURDYNAMICVALUE}", method =RequestMethod.GET)
public String Controller(@PathVariable("YOURDYNAMICVALUE") String YOURDYNAMICVALUE) {
   ...
}
```

or you can just send like

```
   <a href="/csv/downloadIntentCSV?id=${urlvalue}"></a>
```

in the controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/downloadIntentCSV/{id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String Controller(@PathVariable("id") String url) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Actually the main problem is that how i will append dynamically generate URL in href?